# jQuery rules add mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, mask

Good day,

I am support an project that develop by other team.

I saw some jQuery code that I am not really understand what the code is doing, I plan to amend on it but at first I need to know what it want to do first.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
    $(':input[name=country]').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        mask: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
    }); 
});
```

I am suspecting it is mask method, for example which is:

```
$(':input[name=country]').mask("0000-0000"); // this is work
```

But I try to run it but it fail, hitting error:

```
Cannot read property 'call' of jquery.validate.min.js:16 undefined
```

[image]
Any one know what is the code trying to do?

Comment: What is the requirement that you are trying to implement? Why would you plan to amend code that you don't understand - it could be unrelated to whatever your actual requirement is.

Comment: `.mask()` is a different plugin, unrelated to validation.

Comment: It looks to me like the `undefined` value is returned by `$(':input[name=country]')`. Do you have any elements matching that selector in your document?

Comment: @nnnnnn , it is because it hitting some jQuery error, and I want to fix it. I suspect it was some syntax error. Of course, before I amend on it, I sure need to know what it actually wan to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.rules()` method is part of the jQuery Validate plugin and has absolutely nothing to do with the `.mask()` method which is part of another plugin.  This code is trying to dynamically add form validation rules to an `input` element with `name="country"`.

```
$(':input[name=country]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    mask: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/. // <- there is no such rule called 'mask': REMOVE THIS LINE
});
```

The error is because jQuery Validate is looking for a rule called `mask` where there is no "mask" rule in this plugin.

Your only options are:

1. remove all references to this nonexistent rule, OR
2. create a custom rule called `mask` using [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

Answer (score -1):

That code appears to be using the [jQuery Validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to create a [validation rule](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) that the value is required and must consist of only letters, numbers or spaces.

The validation rule is applied to [any input, textarea, select, or button element](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) that has a `name` property with the value of `country`. I suspect the problem is that you don't have one of these fields in your document.

Comment: Its not because of the `country` input field. This field exist, and after I comment the `mask: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/`  , the jQuery error gone. So I am suspecting that is some syntax error of the `mask`, I plan to amend on it but at first I need to know what it want to do first.